# Allowed memory size exhausted in Laravel's CheckForMaintenanceMode middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting the following error in my Laravel 5.2 app:

> E_ERROR: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 73728 bytes)
>
> in
>
> /Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::handle

The error is logged on the server and the error rate is low, which means that the problem is kind of "random", or in other words - occurring only on small percentage of requests.

As far as I know, the CheckForMaintenanceMode is the first middleware to run, on every request. What might be the reason of the memory exhaustion so soon in the request stack? Or, how could I debug this?

BTW, that's all that the middleware checks:

```
public function isDownForMaintenance()
{
    return file_exists($this->storagePath().'/framework/down');
}
```

Comment: Given the actual method code there's no way this could be exhausting your memory.  Something else is pushing memory usage to the limit, and this just happens to be the straw that breaks the camel's back.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a memory leak, Not very easy to pinpoint the real cause. Two solutions here

1- First one is easy as mentioned all of your requests in that moment are accessing a file on your hosts physical drive that might exhaust your Reads to your production instance's physical drive.

You can place in your own custom middleware that checks this Maintenance from the DB instead of that physical file. Plz follow this answers approach for a custom middleware.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-maintenance-mode/replies/32133

You can repilcate this on your dev environment by load testing your app in maintance mode and fix there first.

2 - (Lengthy more time required) You will need to pinpoint which url actually ends up with this error most frequently. You can push your logs to an external party like paper trail or sumologic, Or dig down your log file if you are using the file handler to store logs. Basically something of an event stream can help.

And then you can run blackfire.io on the call to see which function consumes the maximum memory it might give you an idea what is causing this.

Comment: Thanks, Tariq, the second approach put me on the right track. I've pinpointed a specific route which most probably is the source of the leak. I will investigte further but I supposed I have a solid candidate for optimization.